# Oracle database joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Suppose there is one condition,

(+) =

i know (+) used in join of column but what does it mean in this condition

Comment: sorry, read above condition as,
column_name(+)=someValue

Comment: That's the old, deprecated Oracle outer join syntax, can't remember if it's `left join` or `right join`.

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle (+)= syntax is the equivalent for OUTER JOINS.

```
a.column (+)= b.column
```

means "retrieve the record from `b` even if there is no match with `a`" (RIGH OUTER JOIN)

```
a.column = b.column (+)
```

means "retrieve the record from `a` even if there is no match with `b`" (LEFT OUTER JOIN)